# Import and export external javascript code

Tags: javascript

i want to dynamically create `<script>` tag with tracking code in my react app. (when user click accept to enable tracking)

I tried to use something like this

`import analyseScripts from './analyseScripts';`

```
  loadAnalyseScripts() {
    console.log('load analyse scripts');
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = analyseScripts();
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }
```

and export it by:

```
export default function marketingScripts() {
  return (

    (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
        new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
      j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
      'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-5CQF85S');

  )
}
```

But of course export is wrong.
How to achieve something like this as result?

```
<script>
    (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
        new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
      j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
      'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-5CQF85S');
</script>
```

Comment: src is a path to a JavaScript file, not actual javascript code. Unclear why you are not just linking to a JavaScript file.

Comment: what is this function `analyseScripts()` supposed to return?

Comment: @epascarello
because i want to import this code from my repo files, not external script

I updated my question - what i want as a result